# Issue when running jbpm 6.1.0. with apache-tomcat-8.0.23 and java JRE 1.8.0_51

Tags: jbpm

Currently our application runs on jboss without any issues. Current Stack - jbpm 6.1.0.Final , jboss 7, jdk1.7.0_45 , oracle database
We use jbpm api's  to to manage the process state.

We are in the process of upgrading our platform and want to use tomcat going forward. I am trying to port our existing application on the new stack
Tomcat 8.0.23 , Oracle JRE 1.8.0_51 , jbpm 6.1.0.Final & oracle database

Have followed the instructions listed in the below references . 
References:
https://github.com/droolsjbpm/kie-wb-distributions/tree/master/kie-wb/kie-wb-distribution-wars/src/main/assembly/tomcat7

I am getting the below error, Came across similar issues that others faced but could not find the resolution for it.
Eg  https://developer.jboss.org/message/865873#865873

Application is not deployed due to the below error.
Could you please suggest .

Error Log:

```
WARN : No default interceptor found of type org.jbpm.services.task.persistence.TaskTransactionInterceptor might be mssing jbpm-human-task-jpa module on classpath (error null
INFO : CDI BeanManager cannot be found. Not sending event org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.ImplicitServletObjectsHolder$InternalServletContextEvent@2040ca0e with qualifiers [@org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.Initialized()]
INFO : CDI BeanManager cannot be found. Not sending event org.jboss.solder.servlet.WebApplication@ac2b949e with qualifiers [@org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.Initialized()]
INFO : CDI BeanManager cannot be found. Not sending event org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade@138d97cb with qualifiers [@org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.Initialized()]
02-Aug-2015 14:24:40.686 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal One or more listeners failed to start. Full details will be found in the appropriate container log file
02-Aug-2015 14:24:40.686 SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/jbpmproject] startup failed due to previous errors
INFO : CDI BeanManager cannot be found. Not sending event org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.ImplicitServletObjectsHolder$InternalServletContextEvent@25ccdea3 with qualifiers [@org.jboss.solder.servlet.event.Destroyed()]
DEBUG: Context destroyed

SEVERE [localhost-startStop-1] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class com.company.util.ServletJBPMContext
 java.lang.IllegalStateException: No task persistence context available
    at org.jbpm.services.task.commands.TaskContext.getPersistenceContext(TaskContext.java:114)
    at org.jbpm.services.task.commands.InitDeadlinesCommand.execute(InitDeadlinesCommand.java:32)
    at org.jbpm.services.task.commands.InitDeadlinesCommand.execute(InitDeadlinesCommand.java:18)
    at org.jbpm.services.task.commands.TaskCommandExecutorImpl$SelfExecutionCommandService.execute(TaskCommandExecutorImpl.java:65)
    at org.jbpm.services.task.commands.TaskCommandExecutorImpl.execute(TaskCommandExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at org.jbpm.services.task.impl.TaskDeadlinesServiceImpl.initialize(TaskDeadlinesServiceImpl.java:367)
    at org.jbpm.services.task.HumanTaskConfigurator.getTaskService(HumanTaskConfigurator.java:153)
    at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.factory.LocalTaskServiceFactory.newTaskService(LocalTaskServiceFactory.java:65)
    at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.PerRequestRuntimeManager.init(PerRequestRuntimeManager.java:142)
    at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.RuntimeManagerFactoryImpl.newPerRequestRuntimeManager(RuntimeManagerFactoryImpl.java:88)
    at org.jbpm.runtime.manager.impl.RuntimeManagerFactoryImpl.newPerRequestRuntimeManager(RuntimeManagerFactoryImpl.java:79)
    at com.company.util.PerRequestRuntimeManager.getRuntimeManager(PerRequestRuntimeManager.java:58)
    at com.company.util.ServletJBPMContext.contextInitialized(ServletJBPMContext.java:22)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4729)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5167)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:701)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:717)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:945)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1768)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```